# MySQL - continue selecting data from other tables when row in one table does not exist

Tags: mysql

Here are my two tables:

```
customers
--------------------
id     full_name
65     Matt Damon
64     Jimmy Kimmel
63     Guillermo

replacements
--------------------
id     customer_id    devices     reason
40     67             jumpsuit    too big
39     66             banana      too ripe
38     65             hammer      too heavy
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT r.id, c.full_name, r.devices, r.reason
FROM customers c, replacements r
WHERE c.id = r.customer_id
```

What I want to do is continue selecting the rest of the information in the query even when `c.full_name` for that row doesn't exist. For example, I still want it to return the following:

```
id    full_name    devices    reason
40                 jumpsuit   too big
39                 banana     too ripe
38    Matt Damon   hammer     too heavy
```

instead of only

```
id    full_name    devices    reason
38    Matt Damon   hammer     too heavy
```

when `customer_id` number `66` and `67` doesn't exist in the customer's table.

Any references or help in allowing me to understand the solution would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `left join`

```
SELECT r.id, c.full_name, r.devices, r.reason
FROM replacements r
left join customers c on c.id = r.customer_id
```

See [this explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: May you explain how `LEFT JOIN` is different from `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in the link you provided?

Comment: A `left join` is a `left outer join`. You can leave that `outer`